# Can not read getConstants in react nativr pdf

Tags: reactjs

React native 0.72.6
React native pdf 6.7.1
React native blob util 0.18.0
When i run expo start it says can not read getConstants null.
Please tell me the best version

I try many version but not working my android phone version is 11 please help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.